# How to delete Article in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

When I'm trying delete model I'm get this error:

> Action App\Http\Controllers\action('ArticlesController@destroy ') not defined.

What proper way to do this?

Code example:
Form:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => "action('ArticlesController@destroy ')"]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit(['class ' => 'btn btn-danger'] ) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller method:

```
 public function destroy(Article $article)
{
    $article->delete();
    return redirect('articles');
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/','ArticlesController@index');
Route::resource('articles','ArticlesController');
```

ArticlesController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ArticleRequest;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
   class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::all();
        return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('articles.create');
    }

    public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {

            $file = Input::file('file');
            $imgTitle = $request->title;
            $imagePath = 'uploads/' . $imgTitle . '.jpg';
            $request->image_path = $imagePath;
            $request->published_at = Carbon::now();
            Article::create(array('title' => $request->title,
                'body' => $request->body,
                'image_path' => $imagePath, 'published_at' => $request->published_at));

            Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save($imagePath);

            return redirect('articles');
        } else {
            $url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&rsz=1&q=' . $request->title;
            $url = file_get_contents($url);
            $file = json_decode($url);
            $file = $file->responseData->results[0]->url;
            $imgTitle = $request->title;
            $imagePath = 'uploads/' . $imgTitle . '.jpg';
            $request->image_path = $imagePath;
            $request->published_at = Carbon::now();
            Article::create(array('title' => $request->title,
                'body' => $request->body,
                'image_path' => $imagePath, 'published_at' => $request->published_at));

            Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save($imagePath);

            return redirect('articles');
        }

    }

    public function edit(Article $article)
    {
        return view('articles.edit', compact('article'));
    }

    public function update(Article $article, ArticleRequest $request)
    {
        $article->update($request->all());
        return redirect('articles');
    }

//    public function destroy(Article $article,ArticleRequest $request)
//    {
//        $article->delete($request->all());
//        return redirect('articles');
//    }
    public function destroy($id) {

        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        $article->delete();
        return redirect('articles');
    }

public function show(Article $article)
{
    return view('articles.show', compact('article'));
}
```

}

Comment: Your destroy method shows no way of getting the specific article to delete.

Comment: So how can i get it?

Comment: Remove Route::get(). You don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

In your form, you need to send the id of the article which you want to delete

example

This is a form that uses a url you to create an action:

```
 {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'articles' . $article->id)) !!}
                            {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') !!}
                            {!! Form::submit('Delete article', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller and delete action:

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        $article= Article::findOrFail($id);
        $article->delete();

        return redirect('dashboard'); // example....
    }
```

Comment: Same 2 errors No query results for model [App\Article].

Comment: You are using ->firstOrFail(), if your query doesn't return any hits it will throw an exception

Comment: {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'articles' . $article->id)) !!} This is your problem u need to send $article->id, laravel dont know which article u want to delete

Comment: it gives strange url http://localhost/Blog_Laravel/public/articles3 and doesnt delete anything

Comment: I forgot to add slash to artilces, but now it gives `No query results for model [App\Article].`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `find` or `findOrFail` to get the specific Article in question that you want to delete. I prefer `findOrFail` because if the article id does not exist, it will fail and return a 404.

**ArticlesController.php**

```
public function destroy($id) {

    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    $article->delete();
}
```

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['ArticlesController@destroy', $article->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=> 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Note:**

Just so this is documented, your URLs should not reflect the public directory. Currently you have `localhost/Blog_Laravel/public/articles`. Your URL should be `localhost/articles/1` where `1` corresponds to the article.id in the database. This is according to how your routes are setup.

Comment: Now i get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:`

Comment: Well unfortunately It gives 2 new errors `No query results for model [App\Article].`

Comment: Post your entire ArticlesController.

Comment: What route are you hitting to receive `No query results`?

Comment: Also, that's not your entire ArticlesController. Do you have `use App\Article;` at the top?

Comment: I just want to delete article and redirect user to index page

Comment: Did you remove the GET route I stated above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89745/discussion-between-qr11-and-chris-burton).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got this syntax from:

```
'action' => "action('ArticlesController@destroy ')"
```

but it should likely be:

```
'action' => 'ArticlesController@destroy'
```